# as I am her mother

Tags: meaning, as

a. As her mother, I will decide what she will wear to the party.

b. As I am her mother, I will decide what she will wear to the party.

Do the above sentences mean the same?

In (b) it is clear that the speaker thinks that because she is the mother, she has to decide what her daughter will wear. Does (a) mean the same?

Comment: (a) would be the normal way to express that idea.

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same, but the first one is more likely to be used when contrasting advice from two different roles:

> As your friend, I wish you luck, but as your lawyer, I advise you to tread carefully.

The second places more emphasis on **I am**, and might be used if the mother felt that somebody else was challenging her right to decide what her daughter wears.

Answer (score 1):

They do **not** mean the same thing.

**As her mother** means "speaking in my capacity as her mother."

**As I am her mother** means "*because* I am her mother," as you say.